# laravel-mysql WHERE command not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When one of my loggedin user sends a request to another user both of their ids are saved in my database as senderid and recieverid respectively, Now when the reciever logs in I want to check for the reciever id column and also for approval `column=1`.

If receiverid is the same as the loggedin users id then I want to write the content of input field to answer1 column of the same row where reciever id = loggedin user id

the **Table** is here:
[image]

these are the columns of my table

answer1   answer2  recieverid senderid approval

this is my **Controller**

[image]

this is my **View**

[image]

Comment: Please post textual information as plain-text and database details as the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for any relevant tables.

Comment: i have added cloumns of my table please refer to it  :) @tadman

Comment: You're not actually doing anything with your query, just running it without saving the resulting row to a variable.

Comment: oh actually i tried $user->save(); method but that too does'nt worked out for me @JoelHinz

Comment: Not that query. The one starting with `DB::table()`

Comment: then how to do it??? @JoelHinz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `basant` as a model, then, do this:

```
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $query = basant::where('recieverid', Auth::user()->id)->where('approval', 1);

        if ($query->exists()) {
            $user = $query->first();
            $user->answer1 = $request->get('text2');
            $user->save();
        }
    }

    return redirect()->route('autocomplete');
```

Comment: after applying ur answer the page returned an error  "Trying to get property of non-object
"  @kkyeboah

Comment: What do you have on your page? @AbhishekPundir

Comment: i have a input field by the name of text2 @kkyeboah

Comment: Could you update your question with your controller class and blade template? That way we can see what exactly you are doing. @AbhishekPundir

Comment: ill surely can do that @kkyeboah

Comment: I have updated my answer, looks like the user is not logged in before the code hits this controller function. So it tries to get the property `id` from a non-object, which is `Auth::user()`. Also from your description, you want to check that approval = 1 not 0; I updated that too. @AbhishekPundir

Comment: u were right now logged in from the recievers id and the error is gone but the answer is not saved in answer1 column

Comment: That part is just down to the inputs passing the truth test, first of all the user has to be logged in, `recieverid` has to be the same as the logged in user's id and `approval` has to be equal to 1. From your table in your question, all approvals are 0, that means no user will pass this condition, hence nothing will change because the code inside the if condition is never run. @AbhishekPundir